# Calling different JSON files using AJAX via several buttons

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am working on a small project for University using JavaScript, JSON and AJAX to pull information from 3 seperate restaurant menus (stored in JSON files) and displaying them in a list once the relevant button has been clicked.

This worked using one menu, having a button with an event listener that ran the loadAjax function and displayed the relevant menu information.

I've tried to expand this using 3 buttons, with an event listener on each that passes the name of the JSON file through the function parameter. This no longer works, and only the last JSON file is displayed, on window load, without clicking a button.

I'm pretty stuck at this stage and want to avoid having three separate functions (for obvious reasons). The code is below, any help would be much appreciated! I may have made a minor error so apologies if this is a silly question.

```js
 var weekdayBtn = document.getElementById("weekdayBtn"),
 saturdayBtn = document.getElementById("saturdayBtn"),
 sundayBtn = document.getElementById("sundayBtn");

 weekdayBtn.addEventListener("click", loadAjax("weekday.json"), false);
 saturdayBtn.addEventListener("click", loadAjax("saturday.json"), false);
 sundayBtn.addEventListener("click", loadAjax("sunday.json"), false);

 function loadAjax(menuData) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', menuData);
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if ((request.readyState === 4) && (request.status === 200)) {
    var menu = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    var output = "";
    for (var key in menu) {
     output += "<li>" + menu[key]["Title"] + ", " + menu[key]["Description"] + ". " + menu[key]["Price"] + " </li>";
    }
    var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
    menu.innerHTML = output;
   }
  }
  request.send();
 }
```

Comment: To clarify the answer you've received: if the `.addEventListener`'s second parameter contains parens `()` it will execute the function call immediately when the event handler is being set up. You can verify this by looking at the network tab in the developer tools. You'll see all three JSON files are actually loaded. The last one is displayed because it just happens to be called last (during onload). If you switch the order of the event handlers to make the second one last, that one will be the one to show up.  So, `.addEventListener` requires a reference to a function object/ not a func call.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thank you for your explanation. This was very useful.

Comment: There is a better, more modern approach to solving this problem. But since you've accepted that answer I'll leave this alone. Have fun.

Comment: @Randy Casburn: i guess you downvoted my answer without notice the fact that the function i wrote returns a function and that is why it works. addEventListener as any other js function accepts a function call as parameter and it uses its result.

Comment: @mck89 - I did **not** downvote your answer. You answered the question effectively. I do not agree with your approach because it won't scale well over time, but there is nothing _wrong_ with the answer. I personally wish you would have given the explanation, but since you didn't, I did. So all good.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `addEventListener` methods requires a function as second argument so your loadAjax method must return a function:

```
function loadAjax(menuData) {
    return function () {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', menuData);
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if ((request.readyState === 4) && (request.status === 200)) {
                var menu = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                var output = "";
                for (var key in menu) {
                    output += "<li>" + menu[key]["Title"] + ", " + menu[key]["Description"] + ". " + menu[key]["Price"] + " </li>";
                }
                var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
                menu.innerHTML = output;
            }
        }
        request.send();
    }
}
```

in this way the inner function will be used as event listener with the menuData variable in its scope.